# identifier "DDRB" is undefined - VS code / Visual studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, intellisense

I am getting the following error when using the identifier `DDRB`:

> identifier "DDRB" is undefined

But, when I click “go to definition”, the IDE does shows that it can find them. The code also compiles without any problem. I was using VScode first and setting intellisense to "tag parser" did work, but it also got rid of the error checking. So, I switched over to Visual Studio, but the issue remains. In both cases I included the AVR library.

I have googled quite a bit and found some solutions, but most were outdated or did not work. What can I do to resolve this issue?

**"minimal reproducible example:"**

```
#include <avr\io.h>

int main() {

    DDRB |= (1 << DD3);

}
```

Comment: Please provide [mre].

Comment: Try adding `#define __AVR_ATmega32U4__` at the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce same issue in VS2017, and this one can be resolved by adding the `#define __AVR_ATmega32U4__` above the `#include <avr\io.h>` like this:

```
#define __AVR_ATmega32U4__ 
#include <iostream>
#include <avr/io.h>
int main()
{
    DDRB |= (1 << DD3);
}
```

After adding the macro definition, VS Intellisense option can recognize them well and the issue goes away. More details refer to **Kissiel's** [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21804988/10910450). Thanks to him!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to paste this definition into almost every file:

1. press `f1`
2. find `C/C++; Edit configurations (UI)`
3. paste your mcu name in `Defines` section e.g `__AVR_ATmega32U4__`

It worked for me in vs code.

Comment: **+ِ1**! Can't understand why it's not included by default. Very useful!